# How to save the state of the application when you navigate or close the application in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

My application is about getting the contact information of the user when filing an job application. I want for the user to have the ability to save what he/she initially filled up and when he/she wants to finish filling-up the form the information he/she already filled up will there. Is there a way to save the state of the application so that when the user closes the application or navigate to another page the form that the user filled-up wont be gone?

Comment: You can save the information in sqlite and retrieve it later when the application opens. You will have to constantly update the information.

Comment: @SparshaBhattarai that is my first thought. is there another way?

Comment: I'm not aware of any other approach to this. Saving and updating in sqlite could be hectic, so if you have fewer fields and a single user at a time, you can use the persistent dictionary to save user information. For this, you can use the Settings plugin. You can read more about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/configuration-management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the number and types of fields of your application I would use Preferences.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=ios